# Visual studio C#, DLL not found after installing the application

Tags: c#, c++, dll, visual-studio-2019

I have created a DLL in C++ which I would like to import to my C# project.
The application works when I run it in the Visual basic 2019. Later I have created a setup project, when I install the application it still works flawlessly on my computer.

The problem occurs when I install it on another computer, in that case I get the following error:
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NXNqY.png)

The C# code:

```
[DllImport(@".\\shared_lib2.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        static extern void Connect(string str,string str1);
```

Comment: See [Determining Which DLLs to Redistribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/determining-which-dlls-to-redistribute?view=msvc-160&viewFallbackFrom=vs-2019) and [Deployment Examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/deployment-examples?view=msvc-160).

Answer (score 2):

Ok, it seems I have found the issue. The DLL I was trying to init had dependencies. I then searched for them with dumpbin.exe and copied them to the install folder. Now it's working on a freshly installed VM flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

I have met this error and i have fixed it by put .dll file needed to import to the DEBUG folder in my project.

Answer (score 0):

What @Broteamson suggested would technically work, but that would require to you manually add in the DLL after every build.  I recommend adding the DLL to your project in Visual Studio as a dependency.  I've numbered the picture to match the instructions. You'll need to:

1. Right click on Dependencies in your project and select "Add Project References"
2. Select "Browse" and find the DLL you want to include in your project.

Assuming the DLL is compatible with your project everything should work just fine.

[image]

Comment: I have created the DLL with C++, which is the reason Visual studio doesn't let me import it as a reference but I have to use "Dllimport" instead.